# Problem with trying to get all documents with codable class

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, codable

Yesterday I was able with your help to restore using a codable class a specific collection, but now I need to restore a full collection.
My firebase:

[image]

My codable class is:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

// MARK: - Definición clase Evento
class Evento: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let nombre: String
    let estado: Estado
    let precio: Double?
    var imagenes: [String]? = []
    let descripcion: String
    let urlWeb: String?
    let urlRRSS: String?
    let empresa: String?
    let email: String
    let tipo: String
    let ciudad: String
    let fecha: String
    let hora: String
    let lat, long: Double?
    let tags: [String]
    
    // MARK: - Ejemplo de enumerador que indica el estado del Evento
    enum Estado: String, Codable {
        case nopublicado
        case activo
        case retrasado
        case cancelado
        case terminado
    }
}

// MARK: - Inicializador desingado
init(id: String, nombre: String,  estado: Estado, precio: Double?, imagenes: [String]?, descripcion: String, urlWeb: String?, urRRSS: String?, empresa: String, email: String, telefono: String, direccion: String, fecha: String,hora: String, lat: Double?, lon: Double?, tags: [String])
{
    self.id = id
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.estado = Estado.nopublicado
    self.precio = precio
    self.imagenes = []
    self.descripcion = descripcion
    self.urlWeb = nil
    self.urlRRSS = nil
    self.empresa = empresa
    self.email = email
    self.tipo = telefono
    self.ciudad = direccion
    /** RELLENAR CON FECHA ACTUAL*/
    let date = Date()
    let dff = DateFormatter()
    dff.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dfh = DateFormatter()
    dfh.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    self.fecha = dff.string(from: date)
    self.hora = dfh.string(from: date)
    self.lat = 0.0
    self.long = 0.0
    self.tags = tags
}
```

The funcion I use to recover the all documents is:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseFirestore

class Eventos {
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    lazy var eventoActuales = [Evento]()    /// eventos es un array de objeto de la clase Evento
    var eventos:[Evento] = []

    /** Este metodo crea los eventos de inicio*/
    func cargarEventos()
    {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
             db.collection("Eventos").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print ("NO DOCUMENTOS")
                    return
                }
                self.eventos = documents.compactMap({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Evento? in
                    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                    let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let nombre = data["nombre"] as? String ?? ""
                    let descripcion = data["descripcion"] as? String ?? ""
                    print(self.eventos.count)
                    return Evento(id: id, nombre: nombre, estado: Evento.Estado.activo, precio: 10, imagenes: ["test","test"], descripcion: descripcion, urlWeb: "a", urRRSS: "test", empresa: "test", email: "", telefono: "", direccion: "test", fecha: "test",hora: "test", lat: 12, lon: 12, tags: ["test","test"])
                })
             }
    }
```

The mistakes I get is:

```
2022-12-17 02:41:19.842879-0800 eventos[5831:44503] 10.3.0 - [FirebaseFirestoreSwift][I-FST000002] Attempting to initialize or set a @DocumentID property with a non-nil value: "1". The document ID is managed by Firestore and any initialized or set value will be ignored. The ID is automatically set when reading from Firestore.
2022-12-17 02:41:19.843665-0800 eventos[5831:44503] 10.3.0 - [FirebaseFirestoreSwift][I-FST000002] Attempting to initialize or set a @DocumentID property with a non-nil value: "2". The document ID is managed by Firestore and any initialized or set value will be ignored. The ID is automatically set when reading from Firestore.
```

It seems Firestores has some problem with the id, which I defined by writing it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/#a-quick-word-about-mapping-document-ids

Answer (score 0):

The `@DocumentID` wrapper in your `Codable` class `Evento` tells the Firestore Swift API to map that property to the document ID it got from the request.

You're getting the message

```
2022-12-17 02:41:19.842879-0800 eventos[5831:44503] 10.3.0 - [FirebaseFirestoreSwift][I-FST000002] Attempting to initialize or set a @DocumentID property with a non-nil value: "1". The document ID is managed by Firestore and any initialized or set value will be ignored. The ID is automatically set when reading from Firestore.
```

because you're trying to manually assign a value to the `id` property instead of letting the Firestore API populate it with the `Firestore.Decoder`. The [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestoreswift/api/reference/Structs/DocumentID) says that the `DocumentID` wrapper is

> A value that is populated in Codable objects with the DocumentReference of the current document by the Firestore.Decoder when a document is read.

The method `DocumentSnapshot.data(as:with:decoder:)` uses the `Firestore.Decoder` (seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestoreswift/api/reference/Extensions/DocumentSnapshot)) and will decode your data and assign the `id` property with the document ID for you.

In your case, this can be with something along the lines of:

```
func cargarEventos()
    {
        db.collection("Eventos").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print ("NO DOCUMENTOS")
                return
            }
            self.eventos = documents.compactMap({ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Evento? in
                do {
                    let evento: Evento
                    evento = try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Evento.self)
                    print(self.eventos.count)
                    return evento
                }
                catch {
                    // ...
                }
            })
        }
    }
```